# Move data from ColB and ColC beneath data in ColA

Tags: excel, csv

I tried looking up what I need to do, but I'm not very good with Excel, so I'm not sure how to search for what I'm attempting to do.... here it goes...

I have a file that a customer sent me that I need to export as a .csv for direct mailing. What she sent has all 1463 customer names down column A, their address in ColB, and the second address line in ColC. The program that I need to import the .csv file into needs all of the information in one column so that it reads as you might read an address on an envelope, with the entire name and address in one cell (one cell per entry). So I need to take the data in column C and move it underneath the data in column B, then take that data and move it underneath the name data in column A.

Side note: The third address lines did have a comma between the city and state, but I have already gone through and removed them, since I know that the file will not export correctly with a comma in the data in a .csv file.

Using Excel 2010 on Windows 7.

Comment: In column D  `=A1 & CHAR(10) & B1 & CHAR(10) & C1` fill down then copy/paste values to a new sheet.

Comment: That puts everything on one line. I need it to read as if on an envelope with the names on the first line, house address on the second, and the city/state on the third. The .csv doesn't import correctly when done that way.

Comment: @Lauren - you said "with the entire name and address in one cell" - that's what the formula does. Did you turn on text wrapping for the cells with the formula? Or try saving a CSV and look at the content to see if that's what you need.

Comment: Yes! The problem was wrapping! It is now importing correctly with the correct number of data entries, except now it's showing up as just a straight line across on the actual file... like it needs to be formatted in the .csv to show up correctly on the postcards. So it shows Bob Smith1234 RidgewaySt.Austin TX 78726, no spaces or line breaks between the information

Comment: I suppose it's the char10 that isn't working properly? I tried to use char13 instead but to no avail. This is driving me crazy...

Comment: Try both char(10) and char(13) together.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign the formula into cell C1, you can use `=CONCATENATE(A1,CHAR(10),B1)` or `=A1&CHAR(10)&B1`
2. Copy cell C1 and paste it for all required rows in C column
3. Right click on C column header and choose `Wrap Text`
4. Adjust the size of C column so that all lines shown in full

If you save in CSV, you will be asked to confirm features not compatible. If you agree, you need to repeat step 3 two times (Unwrap then Wrap it again) and step 4 if you open this file again. The formula will be gone. I suggest to save in either xls or xlsx format.